# Grafana variables - how to display selected value and label

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I have a Grafana dashboard variable named `items`. The variable is filled with data coming from an API using [JSON API data source](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/marcusolsson-json-datasource/).

My API response is an array of objects containing two properties: `id` and `name` and I have set the name to be the label of my variable. So, in Grafana the dropdown displays a list of names and when I select one or more, it selects the `id`.

However, I want to display the selected values and labels in a text panel below. How can I do that? In the text panel, I can type `$items` and this will show a comma-separated list of selected values, but how can I display a comma-separated list of selected labels, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try advance syntax `${items:value}` or `${items:text}`.

Comment: `${items:value}` does the same as `${items}`, which is okay, but `${items:text}` displays the same, so it doesn't show the labels.

Comment: Quick update: After some restarts (lol), `:text` indeed does return labels separated with a `+` (plus) sign. I do wish I was able to change the plus sign, but it definitely does get the job done. Thanks.